# Xming clipboard only works one way

Tags: clipboard, x11-forwarding, xming

I recently started using Xming to display-back X11 applications from a Linux VM to my Win XP desktop.  It's great -- much more useful than the solution I had before, which used VNC -- but the clipboard behavior is wonky.

At first, I couldn't get the clipboard to sync at all.  I killed and restarted Xming a couple of times, and now it's consistent (but wrong):

- When I copy in Windows, I can paste in Linux or Windows.
- When I copy in Linux, I can paste in Linux but not Windows.
- When I copy in Windows, then select in Linux, the primary (selection) and secondary (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>) buffers both work fine in Linux, but pasting in Windows doesn't work.

Note that when I say pasting in Windows "doesn't work", the Paste menu item is available, indicating Windows thinks there's something on the clipboard, but nothing gets pasted.

Comment: FWIW I now use the XWin Server bundled with Cygwin instead of Xming, and I've never had this issue since switching.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In X-Launch, “Clipboard – Primary Selection – Also map the PRIMARY selection to the Windows clipboard”, uncheck it.

Comment: confirming that playing with the XLaunch settings worked for me too

Comment: For me just running XMing using XLaunch made it work.

Comment: It seems to need a newer version of Xming, not the old 6.9.0.31 version from Sourceforge which is freely available.

Comment: This did not work for me

Comment: I see, this works only in VcXsrv, not in Xming. Just install VcXsrv (see the [other top answer](https://superuser.com/a/596686/265702)) and then follow thiese instructions. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You could try VcXsrv if you are using the public domain version of Xming (6.9.0.31).

https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/

I've just discovered VcXsrv and in my quick test copy/paste works perfectly between Linux and Windows both ways. (Ubuntu 12.04 xterm, emacs and Windows XP)

Comment: I seems that VcXsrv doesn't exist in 32 bits (Windows 7 Pro).

Answer (score 2):

Using VcXsrv `version 1.20.8.1 (7 Apr 2020)`, installed via [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/vcxsrv):

1. right click on the XLaunch icon in the taskbar
2. unselect *Clipboard may use PRIMARY selection*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the ["public domain release"](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming) `Release: 6.9.0.31` it turned out that turning on the `-nodecoration` option, allowed the clipboard from linux to be shared to windows

Using git-bash:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:</path/to/Xming/>
$ Xming :0 -multiwindow -clipboard -nodecoration & 
$ ssh -Y <hostname> "gnome-terminal"
```

I could then highlight text inside the terminal window, and paste it around windows :)

Comment: For me, adding the `-nodecoration` switch also fixed an issue, where the mouse pointer would be misaligned for new windows. Newly created windows are rendered offset slightly outside the screen area for me, and until I manually resize the windows, mouse inputs would be offset twice as far into the opposite direction. With `-nodecoration`, the windows are still placed awkwardly, but mouse input is detected at the correct position.

Comment: Correction: It worked at first, but both issues have returned since.